# Ошибка Broken pipe на сокете

Tags: python, сервер, сокет, chat, messenger

Начну со своего вопроса: я создал мессенджер используя Python Socket, когда я использую двух клиентов к примеру, когда один пользователь выходит из чата, то второй пользователь может отправить ещё 1-2 сообщения и после чего сервер перестает принимать сообщения от остальных пользователей, то есть возникает известная ошибка Broken pipe 32. Терминологию ошибки я осознаю, возможно ошибка кроется на моем сервере в цикле While True ( Цикл, который принимает в себя все действия, которые пользователи проводят между собой ), потому что там есть сказочный код в виде:

```
if not data:
    print(f'User {name1} leave')
    break
```

но он мне необходим, потому что без него сервер в прямом слове улетит, а если сделать похожий механизм, то сервер ещё сможет получить информацию от пользователей.

Надеюсь на взаимопонимание, любая помощь будет принята и одобрена. Код сервера и клиента ниже:

server:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8888

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen(15)
print(f'Server {HOST}:{PORT} start.')

users = [] 
sort = []


def crypto(text, key):
    encrypt = ''

    for i in text:
        encrypt += chr(ord(i) + key)

    return encrypt   


def listen_decode(user, addr):
    print(f'User IP-address {addr[0]} login..')
    sort.append(user) 
    user.send('Encode'.encode('utf-8'))
    user.send('Name'.encode('utf-8'))
    name1 = user.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    users.append(name1)

    
    while True:
        data = user.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        b1 = time.ctime()
        atribute = ' | '
        data_crypto = crypto(data, 4)
        print(f'{name1} sent message: {data_crypto} ' + atribute + '' + b1 + ' ')

        for i in sort:
            if(i != server and i != user):
                i.sendall(f'{name1} > {data}'.encode('utf-8'))
    
        if not data:
            print(f'User {name1} leave')
            break


def start_server():
    
    while True:
       user_socket, addr = server.accept()
       potok_info = threading.Thread(target=listen_decode, args=(user_socket, addr))
       potok_info.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

client:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
import _tkinter 
import socket
import threading
import os


window = Tk()

window.title('Login')
window.geometry('320x200')
window.resizable(True, True)

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8888

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((HOST, PORT))

name = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

def encrypt(text, key):
    encrypt1 = ''

    for i in text:
        encrypt1 += chr(ord(i) - key)

    return encrypt1

def send_message():

    while True:
        data = client.recv(1024)
        print('\r\r' + data.decode('utf-8') + '\n' + f'you: ', end='')


def chat():

    string_name = name.get()

    if('Name' in client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')):
        name1 = string_name
        client.send(name1.encode('utf-8'))

        potok = threading.Thread(target=send_message)
        potok.start()


        while True:
            msg = input('you: ')
            client.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))



def crypt():     
    
    string_name = name.get()
    string_password = password.get()

    try:
        user_encryption_selection = (encryption_listbox.get(encryption_listbox.curselection()))
    except _tkinter.TclError:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Enter type message')



    if string_name == 'John':
        if string_password == '5555':
            if user_encryption_selection == 'Use Encrypted':
                window.after(1000, lambda: window.destroy())

                menu = Tk()

                menu.title('Menu Chat')
                menu.geometry('500x350')
                menu.resizable(False, False)

                menu_button = Button(menu, text='Перейти в глобальный чат', command=chat, height=1, width=18)
                menu_button.grid(padx=150)

                menu.mainloop()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Error password')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Error name')

    
entry = Entry(window, textvariable=name, width=10)
entry.grid(column=1, pady=7, padx=4)

label = Label(window, text='Enter name: ')
label.grid(row=0, padx=1)

entry1 = Entry(window, textvariable=password, width=10)
entry1.grid(column=1, pady=7, padx=2)

label1 = Label(window, text='Enter password: ')
label1.grid(row=1, padx=1)

listbox = Listbox(window, selectmode=SINGLE, width=12, height=2)
listbox.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=7, padx=2)



encryption_options = ['Use Encrypted']
encryption_listbox = Listbox(window, selectmode=SINGLE, width=10, height=1)
encryption_listbox.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=7, padx=2)
for i in encryption_options:
    encryption_listbox.insert(END, i)  

label_crypto = Label(window, text='Type message: ', bg='black', fg='red')
label_crypto.grid(row=2)

button = Button(window, text='Enter', command=crypt)
button.grid(pady=30)



window.mainloop()
```